# Specifying the file detail properties of the output exe

Tags: node-webkit

I'm trying to figure out how to specify the file detail properties of the main executable file used in a Node Webkit app. More specifically, when the end user right-clicks the exe file and chooses 'Properties', then under the 'Details' tab, there are fields for Product Name, Product Version, Copyright, etc etc. These are blank by default. How do I specify the content for these fields?

I would have assumed that I could specify this in my app's manifest.json file, but the "name", "description", and "version" properties in the manifest file seem to have no effect here.

Any ideas? Or workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

Your application is being run by the Node executable, but it looks like the executable is being built without that information being set.

Your best bet is to use a tool like [ResourceHacker](http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/) to edit the resources in the EXE directly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already tried editing the file in both ResourceHacker and ResEdit, but the exe file doesn't appear to have any "version information" associated with it (which I think is what I'm after). Am I out of luck here, or is it still somehow possible to add this data to the exe via a resource editor? I didn't see any obvious ways to do so after spending a few minutes playing around with the res editors, but I'll do a little more digging.

Comment: Alas, I no longer have a Windows machine, so I can't even try this out. I'll see if I can get hold of one though and give it a shot. If it's truly important, you could rebuild the EXE from sources, but really, that's a bit of a mission it seems like.